# How to detect is smartphone in a building?

Tags: android, android-sensors

Task: detect is smartphone in a building (not a street) now.

What is the ways to implement this?

I see one way: switch on GPS and detect signal quality. Is there any other ways? May be it possibly with another sensors?

Answer (score 1):

Please check out Google's [Project Tango](https://get.google.com/tango/). It is a concept of a surroundings-aware device and it could be the answer to your problem. It is still in development, but there is already one phone available that supports it - Lenovo's [Phab 2 Pro](http://shop.lenovo.com/us/en/tango/).

Apart from the above, there is no reliable way to detect if the device is inside, as signal strength and quality may vary even in open areas.

Answer (score 1):

I think you couldn't achive it using "GPS signal quality" because it depends on how many satellites you will catch. Better way is to get actual position via GPS and make map-mask. For example if you're using Google Maps there are a lot of buildings so if your location "overlay" building - you are inside. This is just general case.
P.S. Even GPS with tens of satellites won`t guarantees accurate position.

Comment: Probably the best GPS-based solution, but it will fail in stuff like underground passages or building courtyards :-(